# React native State update on pressing a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to update my full screen on pressing a button. I have tried updating States but is not working for my case. I don't know if its causing for the async function or not.
This is my states:

```
    const [bNumber, setBNumber] = React.useState('');
    const [rollNumWeight, setRollNumWeight] = useState([]);
    const [rollNumber, setRollNumber] = useState('');
    const [rollWeight, setRollWeight] = useState('');
```

Bellow is function I am using:

```
const saveRoll = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('someURL', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                roll_num_weight: rollNumWeight,
                bNumber: bNumber
              })
            });
            const json = await response.json();
            setBNumber('')
            setRollNumber('')
            setRollWeight('')
            setRollNumWeight([])
            AlertButton('Rolls Saved Successfully!')
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
    }
```

**I am inputting some data on this stage so my states changes from initial state. Then I am pressing SAVE button**

This is the button I am calling my function from:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={saveRoll}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Save</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

After Pressing the save button it nothing changes. All the states remain the same.

Bellow is my full render code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView 
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <View style={styles.app}>
                <View style={styles.col1}>
                        <Text>WORKORDER/BATCHNO</Text>
                        <SelectDropdown
                            data={batches}
                            onSelect={(selectedItem) => {
                                // getData(selectedItem)
                                setBNumber(selectedItem)
                            }}
                            defaultButtonText={'Select Batch NO'}
                            buttonTextAfterSelection={(selectedItem, index) => {
                            return selectedItem;
                            }}
                            rowTextForSelection={(item, index) => {
                            return item;
                            }}
                            buttonStyle={styles.input}
                            buttonTextStyle={styles.dropdown1BtnTxtStyle}
                            renderDropdownIcon={isOpened => {
                            return <FontAwesome name={isOpened ? 'chevron-up' : 'chevron-down'} color={'#444'} size={18} />;
                            }}
                            dropdownIconPosition={'right'}
                            dropdownStyle={styles.dropdown1DropdownStyle}
                            rowStyle={styles.dropdown1RowStyle}
                            rowTextStyle={styles.dropdown1RowTxtStyle}
                            selectedRowStyle={styles.dropdown1SelectedRowStyle}
                            search
                            searchInputStyle={styles.dropdown1searchInputStyleStyle}
                            searchPlaceHolder={'Search here'}
                            searchPlaceHolderColor={'darkgrey'}
                            renderSearchInputLeftIcon={() => {
                            return <FontAwesome name={'search'} color={'#444'} size={18} />;
                            }}
                        />
                </View>
                <View pointerEvents="none">

                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <View style={styles.col1}>
                        <Text>Roll Number</Text>
                        <TextInput 
                        placeholder='Roll Number'
                        keyboardType='numeric'
                        style={styles.input}
                        value={rollNumber}
                        onChangeText={(val) => setRollNumber(val)} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.col1}>
                        <Text>Roll Weight</Text>
                        <TextInput 
                        placeholder='Roll Weight'
                        keyboardType='numeric'
                        style={styles.input}
                        value={rollWeight}
                        onChangeText={(val) => setRollWeight(val)} />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <Button title='      Add      ' onPress={addRoll}></Button>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={saveRoll}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Save</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
                <Row data={tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>
                <Rows data={rollNumWeight} textStyle={styles.text}/>
            </Table>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: is the fetch request send? you can check it in the network tab

Comment: Yes fetch request is working fine. In fact whatever command I am putting inside try block doesn't seems to work.

Comment: can you show more of the render?
might lay there